# My app is not showing in Django admin panel

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have problem with Django admin panel. I have two apps: 'users' and 'advertisements'. App 'users' was installed before app 'advertisements'. Both apps are included in 'INSTALLED_APPS', but in admin panel showing only app 'users'. What problem can it be? Thanks a lot.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'phonenumber_field',
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'advertisements.apps.AdvertisementsConfig',
]
```

advertisementes/apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class AdvertisementsConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'advertisements'
```

advertisements/admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *


class AdvertisingSpaceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'title', 'description', 'slug', 'data', 'user')
    


admin.site.register(AdvertisingSpace, AdvertisingSpaceAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your configuration looks alright. Try disabling your adblocking software. The app is called `advertisements` and probably the browser extension considers it an ad and blocks it.

Comment: Yes, i found it a week ago, but thank you for answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try registering the apps like this:

```
admin.site.register(AdvertisingSpace)
admin.site.register(AdvertisingSpaceAdmin)
```

Comment: TypeError: 'MediaDefiningClass' object is not iterable

Answer (score 0):

If you are not working with signals, for example, there is no point of adding `users.app.UsersConfig` into INSTALLED_APPS. Just add the app name into INSTALLED_APPS as 'users' only.

Other point that you are doing in which is not a good practice is importing your models like this:

`from .models import *`

The best way you can do is importing only the model you want or all of them (EXPLICITLY) to avoid any error.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but this isn't work for me too :(